# SQL Server SSIS issue retrieve data when I enter into login of server side?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-recommendation

I am failing to retrieve data when I enter into login of server side.

Here is the error message

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------
Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

For help, click: 
------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

The server principal "dbkvsstaging" is not able to access the database "vssgis1" under the current security context. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 916)

For help, click: 
------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

I tried to follow [this article](http://rajeshssingh.blogspot.in/2010/02/exception-occurred-while-executing.html) to solve this problem, which suggested:

> Step 3: You will see a panel will open at the right hand side,
>
> Step 4: Right click on the header part of that panel, and unselect all option, as shown in the image,

However, I didn't find any panel when I pressed F7. I found object explore detail only, but  didn't  find the listpanel on my pc at the right hand side, as mentioned in Step 4.